# Making texture paint only stay in the selected faces - with no bleeding

Tags: uv, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

I want to make UV maps for a game similar to Minecraft where there is no texture filtering. I tried "Smart UV Project" which packs all of the faces together in the UV map. But when using texture paint it goes outside of the selected faces:

[image]

That makes the pink go onto faces that weren't selected.

With "Lightmap Pack" there are gaps between the faces in the UV map but it still goes onto the wrong faces:

[image]

Notice the thin green areas

[image]

I don't understand why it is painting outside of the selected faces.

I noticed that for "Smart UV Project" there were 49 rows and columns of squares so I tried making the texture 490 x 490 - but it still has the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the brush options, choose a *Bleed* value of 0:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! BTW to find it I had to go to "Texture Paint" then tools... "Paint" also has Brushes which looks almost the same...